# [[NSMutableArray alloc]init] causing crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following class:

```
#import "SharedData.h"
static int selectedCountryIndex;
static NSMutableArray *imageDataObjectsArray;
@implementation SharedData
+(void)insertIntoImageDataObjectsArray:(ImageData *)imageData:(int)index{
    if (!imageDataObjectsArray)
        **imageDataObjectsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];**

    [imageDataObjectsArray insertObject:imageData atIndex:index];
}
+(ImageData *)getFromImageDataObjectsArray:(int)index{
    return [imageDataObjectsArray objectAtIndex:index];
}
+(void)setSelectedCountryIndex:(int)selectedCountryIndexArg{
    selectedCountryIndex = selectedCountryIndexArg;
}
+(int)getSelectedCountryIndex{
    return selectedCountryIndex;
}
@end
```

This class is just meant to accept data from one view, and then allow another view to fetch that data. However, whenever the insertIntoImageDataObjectsArray method is called, the line marked with asterisks causes an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" crash. This is the call to that method:

```
[SharedData insertIntoImageDataObjectsArray:imageDataObject :[result doubleValue]-1];
```

Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Show the error message. That line can't really crash

Comment: check out whether your index is negative value..

Comment: The error message is in the question: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS". That's all it's giving me.

Comment: Did you single step through to see where it actually dies?

Comment: Nevermind. Vishy was correct - it was a negative index value.

Comment: Don't prefix methods with `get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect it is this line that is crashing:

```
[imageDataObjectsArray insertObject:imageData atIndex:index];
```

And I expect it is crashing because you are attempting to insert at an index that is larger than the array.

```
0 => "value1",
1 => "value2"
```

`[imageDataObjectsArray insertObject:@"value3" atIndex:1];` would succeed and produce

```
0 => "value1",
1 => "value3",
2 => "value2"
```

Subsequently calling `[imageDataObjectsArray insertObject:@"value4" atIndex:5];` would fail
as index 5 > max index (2)

Or as a commenter pointed out, **a negative number is also invalid as an index**

Comment: I changed [imageDataObjectsArray insertObject:imageData atIndex:index]; to [imageDataObjectsArray addObject:imageData]; and I still get the same problem.

Comment: Are you using ARC? It could be that your array was prematurely deallocated.

Comment: I am using ARC. How do I make sure that it isn't deallocated prematurely? I figured the whole point of making it static was that it wouldn't be deallocated.

Comment: I just noticed that 3 objects are added to the array before it crashes, if that provides any clues.

Comment: But an invalid index would not produce a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.